# Python null check import xls

Tags: python

There is a python code which reads from a field xls file

The script works, but there are problems when there are empty fields in the file

The script does not read the field if the file has an empty field

My code, for example, here the NORD field is empty:

```py
from msexcel8com import *


def convert(dsIn, dsOut):
    import sys

    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
    import msexcel8com

    xlsApp = msexcel8com.Application()
    xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(unicode(dsIn["PATH_TO_XLS"]))
    xlsWorkbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Item(1)
    xlsWorksheet = xlsWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    xlsWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(11, None).Activate()
    rowsCount = xlsApp.ActiveCell.Row
    import msxml2

    dsOut.clear()
    outXML = msxml2.DOMDocument()
    RootNode = outXML.createElement("MSG")
    RootNode.setAttribute("FORMAT", "IMPORT_LN")
    ChildNodes = outXML.appendChild(RootNode)
    i, k, c = 1, 1, 2
    while i < rowsCount:
        i = i + 1
        if k > c:
            k = 0
            dsOut.append()
            dsOut["XML_OUT"] = unicode.encode(outXML.xml, "utf-8")
            outXML = msxml2.DOMDocument()
            RootNode = outXML.createElement("MSG")
            RootNode.setAttribute("FORMAT", "IMPORT_LN")
            ChildNodes = outXML.appendChild(RootNode)
        try:
            TMPNode = outXML.createElement("CLIENT")
            TMPNode.setAttribute("NCODE", xlsWorksheet.Cells.Item(i, 1).Value)
            TMPNode.setAttribute("NORD", xlsWorksheet.Cells.Item(i, 2).Value)
            ChildNodes.appendChild(TMPNode)
            k = k + 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    dsOut.append()
    dsOut["XML_OUT"] = unicode.encode(outXML.xml, "utf-8")
    try:
        xlsApp.Workbooks.Close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    try:
        xlsApp.Quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

How to make sure that even if there is an empty field, return as null and the rest of the values?

Comment: I'd suggest using pandas to read in your xls file, seems like the most clean solution, not looking too deep in your function

Comment: What errors do you get? Unless there's a specific need to do COM automation with Excel here, I'd really recommend looking into `openpyxl` or `xlrd` for reading Excel files and the built-in `xml` modules for writing XML.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist the temptation of writing this without all that Excel automation.
Assuming an Excel file that looks something like this called `so59715137.xls`:
[image]

```py
import xlrd  # assuming it's an .xls, not .xlsx
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


def read_rows(xls_filename, column_labels):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_filename)
    sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    for rx in range(sh.nrows):
        yield dict(zip(column_labels, sh.row_values(rx)))


def convert(xls_filename):
    xml_root = et.Element("MSG", {"FORMAT": "IMPORT_LN"})
    for row in read_rows(xls_filename, ("NCODE", "NORD")):
        print(row)  # for debugging
        if row.get("NCODE") and row.get("NORD"):  # both attributes must be truthy
            et.SubElement(xml_root, "CLIENT", attrib=row)  # just use the dict as attributes

    return et.tostring(xml_root, encoding="unicode")


xml_content = convert("so59715137.xls")
print("-------------------------------")
print(xml_content)
# TODO: write to file
```

outputs (with debugging output included, so you see it reads but elides the rows that are missing data)

```
{'NCODE': 'foo', 'NORD': 'faa'}
{'NCODE': 'blep', 'NORD': 'blop'}
{'NCODE': 'missing', 'NORD': ''}
{'NCODE': '', 'NORD': 'other-missing'}
-------------------------------
<MSG FORMAT="IMPORT_LN"><CLIENT NCODE="foo" NORD="faa" /><CLIENT NCODE="blep" NORD="blop" /></MSG>
```

From there on out, it's easy to read/write your `dsIn`/`dsOut` structures.